# BindDataGrid() Function is not calling under handleMonthChange(event) in react.js. handleMonthChange is calling whenever value is selected in dropdown

Tags: reactjs

function handleMonthChange(event) {
setData(data => ({ ...data, month: event.target.value }));

```
BindDataGrid();
```

}

function BindDataGrid() {

```
if (typeof month === "undefined") {
  const smonth= month.Result_Month

 //fetch(ParameterResultURL + '?' + new URLSearchParams({ EntityID: entity, ProcUnitID: processunit , ParamID:parameter , Month:(month==undefined?'1/1/2022':month)} ))

fetch(ParameterResultURL + '?' + new URLSearchParams({ EntityID: entity, ProcUnitID: processunit , ParamID:parameter , Month:smonth} ))
 .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((rowData) => setRowData(rowData));
} else {
  month = "undefined"
 }
```

}

Comment: Which function is not called? Extend your example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to call BindDataGrid()

Answer (score 0):

You can put an async function into the useEffect hook to re-render whenever you change the data. You will need to re-write it a little to use async/await. But then you could add "data" to the dependency array and it will re-render when you update the data.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const BindDataGrid = async () => {
        if (typeof month === "undefined") {
            const smonth= month.Result_Month
    
            //fetch(ParameterResultURL + '?' + new URLSearchParams({ EntityID: entity, ProcUnitID: processunit , ParamID:parameter , Month:(month==undefined?'1/1/2022':month)} ))
    
            await fetch(ParameterResultURL + '?' + new URLSearchParams({ EntityID: entity, ProcUnitID: processunit , ParamID:parameter , Month:smonth} ))
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then((rowData) => setRowData(rowData));
        } else {
        month = "undefined"
        }

        BindDataGrid();
}, [data]) // Re-run whenever data changes

function handleMonthChange(event) { 
    setData(data => ({ ...data, month: event.target.value }));
}
```